# Generating HTML forms

Tags: javascript, radio-button, innerhtml

I am trying to do the following with an HTML form and some JavaScript:

A checkbox that when checked generates two radio buttons dynamically and a text that says “Checkbox 1 is checked”.

The logic (seen in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jPcP/) does work, but for some reason, the two radio buttons can’t be selected.  When I click on either radio button nothing happens.  I’d appreciate it if any of you guys have some input on what I might be doing wrong.

Note: The sequence doesn’t seem to work (radio buttons are indeed generated dynamically) on jsFiddle but it does work on my workstation.

HTML code:

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="sequenceOP" id="sequenceOP14" onChange="displaySequence()">
Checkbox 1<br/>
<div id="displayText"></div>
<div id="variableSpdExhOptions"></div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function displaySequence(){
var displayVariableExhOptions = "";
var displayText = "";
if(sequenceOP14.checked){
displayText += "Checkbox 1 is checked";
displayVariableExhOptions += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"exhOptions\" id=\"sequenceOP15\" onChange=\"displaySequence()\" >"
+ "Radio Box 1<br/>"
+ "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"exhOptions\" id=\"sequenceOP16\" onChange=\"displaySequence()\" >"
+ "Radio Box 2<br/>"
}
document.getElementById("variableSpdExhOptions").innerHTML = displayVariableExhOptions;
document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = displayText;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have on change in your radio buttons when your if statement only checks for the check box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is is the fix for your issue: [Fix JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/9jPcP/4/).

Basically what was wrong is your JS was been loaded on domReady and then discard.

You want it to be loaded in the head.

Code Here:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[ 

        function ds() {

            var displayVariableExhOptions = "";
            var displayText = "";
            if (document.input.sequenceOP14.checked) {
                displayText += "Checkbox 1 is checked";
                displayVariableExhOptions += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"exhOptions\" id=\"sequenceOP15\" onChange=\"displaySequence()\" >" + "Radio Box 1<br/>" + "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"exhOptions\" id=\"sequenceOP16\" onChange=\"displaySequence()\" >" + "Radio Box 2<br/>"
            }
            document.getElementById("variableSpdExhOptions").innerHTML = displayVariableExhOptions;
            document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = displayText;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<form name="input" action="" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="sequenceOP" id="sequenceOP14" onChange="ds();">
Checkbox 1<br/>
<div id="displayText"></div>
<div id="variableSpdExhOptions"></div>
</form>
```

To save you worrying about ids make it a bit easier for yourself:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sequenceOP" id="sequenceOP14" onChange="ds(this);">

  function ds(obj) {

            var displayVariableExhOptions = "";
            var displayText = "";
            if (obj.checked) {
```

Comment: Thank for the js fiddle help. I did not see that "onLoad"

Comment: Thats great glad i am able to help!

Comment: Hi LmC, thank you for your input but your code does unfortunately the same thing as mine.  The two radio buttons are indeed generated but they’re unselectable which is what my problem is.

Comment: Hi Sorry to here this but it seems to be working perfect for me on that JS Fiddle (Tested in Chrome/Firefox)

Comment: There is something wrong with your onChange. The escape char look correct

Comment: Ummm, I'll further my debugging and post a comment if I find the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/9jPcP/5/ Thats it without escape char theres no need for them

Comment: Turns out I've got a few more bugs.  I'll work them out but your answer did solve my problem, thanks LmC

Comment: Great anymore give me a shout

Answer (score 2):

```
if(sequenceOP14.checked){
```

In here you have not accessed the DOM. you need to use `document.getElementById("sequenceOP14")`

Comment: I might be wrong, But in the case of a form is the best action not document.formname.elementname.value or .checked in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Where does your "sequenceOP14" comes from?

You need to pass the checkbox to your javascript function like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sequenceOP" id="sequenceOP14" onChange="displaySequence(this)">
```

Then in your javascript function:

```
function displaySequence(htmlCheckableElement){
    if(typeof(htmlCheckableElement) == "undefined")
        return;
    var displayVariableExhOptions = "";
    var displayText = "";
    if(htmlCheckableElement.checked){
        displayText += "Checkbox 1 is checked";
        displayVariableExhOptions += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"exhOptions\"                         id=\"sequenceOP15\" onChange=\"displaySequence()\" >"
        + "Radio Box 1<br/>"
        + "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"exhOptions\" id=\"sequenceOP16\" onChange=\"displaySequence()\" >"
        + "Radio Box 2<br/>"
        }
        document.getElementById("variableSpdExhOptions").innerHTML = displayVariableExhOptions;
        document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = displayText;
    }
}
```

Comment: LmC's answer helped me.  +1 for you effort though